# Unit testing a Spring Boot service class with(out) repository in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot based webservice with following structure:

Controller (REST) --> Services --> Repositories  (as suggested in some tutorials).

My Database Connection (JPA/Hibernate/MySQL) is defined in a @Configuration class. (see below)

Now I'd like to write simple tests for methods in my Service classes, but I don't really understand how to load ApplicationContext into my test classes and how to mock the JPA / Repositories.

This is how far I came:

My service class

```
@Component
public class SessionService {
    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
    public void MethodIWantToTest(int i){
    };
    [...]
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SessionServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SessionService sessionService() {
            return new SessionService();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    SessionService sessionService;
    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
    [...]
  }
}
```

But I get following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.myApp.SessionRepository
>   com.myApp.SessionService.sessionRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.myApp.SessionRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

For completeness: here's my @Configuration for jpa:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.myApp.repositories"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {


    @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException, IOException {
        ...
    }

   @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        ...
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
   ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
  ... 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to load the context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class Demo{
    @Test
    void contextLoad(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test Spring will use configuration only from inner ContextConfiguration class.  This class describes your context. In this context you created only service bean and no repository. So the only bean that will be created is SessionService. You should add description of SessionRepository in inner ContextConfiguration. Your JpaConfig class will not be used in test class(you don't specify this), only in application.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. But the repositories are interfaces, how can I instantiate them like SessionService?!

Comment: You said that application has structure Controller (REST) --> Services --> Repositories. This means that Repositories are classes that access database (DAOs). So if SessionRepository is interface you should have its implementation in your app. In other case when you will start your project Spring will get the same exception because it will not find any class that implements specified interface.

Comment: Boot uses Spring-Data-JPA ( http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) where you only define an interface and spring somehow provides the implementation automatically. In my Services I just @Autowire them, but no Idea how this is supposed to work with testing.

Comment: Ok, I understood what do you want. First try to launch test on JpaConfig application context. You should try to use this annotation on text class @ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaConfig.class})

Comment: mh got that, but doesn't change the exception.

Comment: This should work @ContextConfiguration(classes=JpaConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class). You may see examples here http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/